# Import code coverage from PHPUnit to sonarqube

Tags: php, sonarqube, phpunit, code-coverage

I have problem with import code coverage raport from PHPUnit into Sonarqube.

- SonarCube V7.4
- PhpUnit 5.7.2
- PHP 7.3.4.1

*phpunit.xml*

```xml
 <logging>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="_reports/logs/clover.xml"/>
        <log type="coverage-xml" target="_reports/coverage/coverage.xml"/>
        <log type="testdox-text" target="_reports/testdox/executed.txt"/>
 </logging>
```

*sonar-project.proporties*

```
sonar.tests=tests
sonar.php.coverage.reportPaths=tests/_reports/logs/clover.xml
```

After run tests in phpunit, reports are generated properly in tests/_reports.
After run analize by sonar, analize passing successfull without fails, but coverage is not visible.

I don't know where i'm doing mistake in my configs. What can I do for reslove it? 
Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpUnit 5.7.2 generates xml coverage with absolute path, if you are using vagrant or docker, and then running sonar on windows check if those paths are valid. 
Next time run sonar with -X flag to get more information.

Comment: Thanks you, you're right, i'm using vagrant and problem was with paths.

Comment: I had the same problem with Docker. To fix it I ran sonar-scanner from the container with the project where the paths of classes were generated by PHPUnit. After it I had the coverage within SonarQube.